# Why wont my code printf an array after a for loop?

Tags: c, binary, printf, pixel

I have a project in progress where we must read a binary file which contains the pixels of an image and bring out the RGB components, to have components between 0 and 255. So I did this only my program does not printf anything, I don't know why (here I'm just trying to printf the first Pixgreen value which is the array containing the red component of each pixel).

```
int main(void) {

    FILE *f_in = fopen("Pixmap.bin", "rb"); // ”rb" ouverture en lecture, binaire
    if(f_in == NULL ) {
        perror("Erreur lors de l'ouverture en lecture\n");
        return -1;
    }


    unsigned int myH;
    size_t r2 = fread(&myH, sizeof(myH), 1, f_in);
    printf("Hauteur: %d \n", myH);

    unsigned int myW;
    size_t r3 = fread(&myW, sizeof(myW), 1, f_in);
    printf("Largeur: %d \n", myW);


    int *Pix=malloc(myH*myW*sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < myW*myH; ++i) {
        size_t r4= fread(&Pix[i], sizeof(Pix), 1, f_in);
        //printf("0x%08X,", Pix[i]);
        //printf("%d,", Pix[i]);
    }
    free(Pix);


    fclose(f_in);

    int Pixred[myW*myH];
    int Pixgreen[myW*myH];
    int Pixblue[myW*myH];

    for (int q=0; q<myH; q++) {
        for (int s=0; s<myW; s++) {
            //Pixred[myW*q+s]=(Pix[myW*q+s]&0xFF0000)>>16;
            //Pixgreen[myW*q+s]=(Pix[myW*q+s]&0x00FF00)>>8;
            //Pixblue[myW*q+s]=(Pix[myW*q+s]&0x0000FF)>>0;
            Pixred[myW*q+s]=(Pix[myW*q+s] >> 16) & 0xff;
            Pixgreen[myW*q+s]=(Pix[myW*q+s] >> 8) & 0xff;
            Pixblue[myW*q+s]=Pix[myW*q+s] & 0xff;
        }
    }

    printf("%d,\n",Pixred[1]);
    fflush(stdout);

} // was missing...
```

Comment: When you run this with a debugger, what is the *first* thing it does incorrectly?

Comment: You read ints but the pixel elements are bytes (1 byte for each color).

Comment: Maybe you have some problems with your file, I tried your code and it prints stuff. I just added ```#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE``` to get rid of the deprecation warning.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Code is reading an int *for each RGB*, then isolating each color/byte from that.  Still might not be right, but not as wrong as you make it sound.

Comment: @ScottHunter, so pixels are encoded as RGB0 (4 bytes pp)?

Comment: Maybe I'm not really understading what is happening in my code. Once I use the mask on the pixels, am I directly supposed to get values between 0 and 255 or should I add something? The file is as follows: 854, 480 , 11272620 // pixel 0
11272643 // pixel 1 …, …, 14272556 // last pixel. Tried to add the #define as suggested by @MireaRadu but it still doesn't print anything.

Comment: Also I do not know if I should convert the values in Pix to hexadecimals for the mask to work in the for loop or if I should keep it as such. And if so, I'm not sure how to convert it to hexadecimals, does printing "0x%08X" just do the job?